# How to send events from the dap to the frontend (frame change, breakpoint changes)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

From the [Debug Adapter Protocol Specification](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification) it is quite clear how to react on frontend changes. For example: when the user selects a frame so the dap backend is getting an event, the user changes a breakpoint, so a `SetBreakpointsRequest()` is received.

But how to send "insights" to the frontend, for example when the backend recognizes a breakpoint change or a change of active frame by the debugger?

Note: I've directly tried to add them in the backend with the following code - but as long as that was in the debugging did not start and neither output panes nor debugging pane showed any reason.

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

    var loc = new vscode.Location(vscode.Uri.file(file), new vscode.Position(line,0));
    var bp = new vscode.SourceBreakpoint(loc);
    vscode.debug.addBreakpoints([bp]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A debugger adapter can update breakpoints with an event. See https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Events_Breakpoint

> The event indicates that some information about a breakpoint has changed.

```
interface BreakpointEvent extends Event {
  event: 'breakpoint';

  body: {
    /**
     * The reason for the event.
     * Values: 'changed', 'new', 'removed', etc.
     */
    reason: 'changed' | 'new' | 'removed' | string;

    /**
     * The `id` attribute is used to find the target breakpoint, the other
     * attributes are used as the new values.
     */
    breakpoint: Breakpoint;
  };
}
```

The `Breakpoint` object contains an `id` that you can use to reference an existing breakpoint.

A typical scenario for this would be when you start debugging, the code is loaded in your runtime and a breakpoint is automatically moved from a no-code line to the next line with code. This is how the Debug Adapter would signal to the IDE that it needs to update the breakpoint location.

Generally the specification section "Requests" is something that gets initiated by the IDE (usually the user) and the section "Events" is something that gets initiated by the Debug Adapter or the Debugger Engine Backend...

Note, all this is only possible when a debug session is active. If you have some other requirements, that your extension should modify breakpoints and such while there is no active session, or perhaps do something that is not covered by the DAP specification, you will need to implement some extension code and use the `vscode.debug` API https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug